# Meaning of a sentence changed by a comma

Tags: commas

Can someone explain or re-write/paraphrase the meaning of these two paragraphs in plain English (last one has a serial comma before 'or elsewhere'):

> if a Man do levy War against our Lord the King in his Realm, or be adherent to the King’s Enemies in his Realm, giving to them Aid and Comfort in the Realm or elsewhere

> if a Man do levy War against our Lord the King in his Realm, or be adherent to the King’s Enemies in his Realm, giving to them Aid and Comfort in the Realm, or elsewhere

Comment: Those are not sentences.  If I were to make them into sentences...

Comment: See answer at https://english.stackexchange.com/a/316701/131620

Comment: It is regarding the legal definition of treason in British law. Roger Casement was executed in 1916 due up the comma in the second version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sentence, it could be argued that *or elsewhere* refers only to giving Aid and Comfort.  In the second sentence, *or elsewhere* refers to all three – levy War, adherent ... to Enemies, and giving Aid and Comfort.

Your Q is related to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/430531/is-the-solution-of-the-maine-legislature-to-the-oxford-comma-case-clunky), but is not a duplicate.

Comment: See https://www.irishhistorycompressed.com/significant-commas-in-irish-history/

Comment: @K1eran I inferred that the sentence fragment had to do with treason, but did not track it down.  Many thanks!